# Are there any protections or policies people do differently in case of a large scale police walkout?

Tags: united-states, georgia

Recently Atlanta has begun a police walkout, in which the police in certain zones are no longer able to respond to the majority of calls. In case something like this happens where I live, are there policies in place that a business or home owner needs to know in case of a break in? In particular if I stop someone at gunpoint, am I allowed to now hold or transport a person I find breaking and entering if the police cannot come to take them? Do I just let them go?

Answer (score 1):

Georgia law statutorily recognizes the common law right of citizen's arrest in [OCGA 17-4](https://law.justia.com/codes/georgia/2010/title-17/chapter-4/article-4/). [17-4-61](https://law.justia.com/codes/georgia/2010/title-17/chapter-4/article-4/17-4-61/) *requires* you to take the arrestee before a judicial officer, or to deliver him to the police.

> A private person who makes an arrest pursuant to Code Section 17-4-60
> shall, without any unnecessary delay, take the person arrested before
> a judicial officer, as provided in Code Section 17-4-62, or deliver
> the person and all effects removed from him to a peace officer of this
> state.

You must do so immediately, and the person [must be released](https://law.justia.com/codes/georgia/2010/title-17/chapter-4/article-4/17-4-62/) if they are not brought before a judicial officer within 48 hours.